# Can Kurento run as a WebSocket client?

Tags: server, client, nat, kurento

I understand that Kurento *Server* is called this way for a reason, but can it be configured (or hacked) to run as a client in terms of the [Kurento Protocol](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mastering/kurento_protocol.html)?

According to the Kurento 6.6.1 documentation:

> Previous to issuing commands, the Kurento Client requires establishing
>   a WebSocket connection with Kurento Media Server to the URL:
>   `ws://hostname:port/kurento`

But since we would like to run our Kurento Server behind NAT that doesn't have a dedicated IP address and doesn't allow DDNS and port forwarding, it would be really nice if Kurento could connect to our signaling server (WebSocket-based) and permanently sustain that connection. When web-based client connects to that signaling server, a connection would be negotiated between the WebRTC server (Kurento) and the client (browser) via signaling. – Well, that's our hope, at least, since RTSP connection to our camera also cannot be established from the Internet.

See the diagram of what we are trying to achieve:

[image: Kurento runs behind NAT together with video source, it connects to WS and TURN servers on the Internet, browser connects to WS and TURN servers to receiver WebRTC stream from Kurento]

Thanks.